# UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java245

Tags: java, eclipse, path

I'm having a difficult time figuring this one out. I have an eclipse project where I created a user library which includes the jar file `opencv_java245.jar`.

I've tried everything I can think of, adding the jar to the path, adding the directory of the jar to the path variable. 
I checked my java versions, I've tried VM arguments in run config.
I still get the same `UnsatisfiedLinkError` on this line `System.loadLibrary("opencv_java245");`

Right now I have a user library with `opencv-245.jar` located in `C:\OpenCV\opencv\build\java`
The Native Library Location for it is located in `C:/OpenCV/opencv/build/java`
My `PATH` variable also has that same location added to it.

Comment: what do you want to do? I see no context, so it is hard to tell what the problem is and to find a solution. Please give me more context.

Comment: I'm trying to run the wonderful opencv libraries. 
I'm not sure what other context I can put on, it's just loading a library and running the command System.loadLibrary("opencv_java245"); which causes an UnsatisfiedLinkError. I don't know why it's happening.

Answer (score 1):

```
 System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
```

this the code for detect default dll  file..

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is so short / only code. Would you mind expanding it by adding some text to explain how it solves the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Actually for future reference for anyone I found the solution. Inside the java folder for OpenCV there is a x64 and x86 folder containing dll files for OpenCV. Copy over either 64 bit or 32 bit dll file to your java folder for OpenCV and it should work.

Comment: Have you ever got this working when you package your project up and distribute it?